# Realms database not setting Int or Long

Tags: c#, android, database, xamarin, realm

I'm using Realms Database in some Xamarin Android project and having troubles saving RealmObjects. My Object have some int and long variables that give this error in constructor:

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Realms.RealmObject.SetInt64Value'
```

Anybody in the same point??

Comment: Have you enabled linking in your app and are you using reflection to call your property setters?

Comment: All entities are linked as RealmObjects. I'm just using local database, Nikola. There is another method to send data to the server.

Comment: I meant, have you enabled the Xamarin linker (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/) - I imagine it's possible that it has removed some of the methods from the Realm assembly if it thought they are not needed.

Comment: Not anabled in this one. It's a small app. 

Anything else in mind??

I'm near to quit Realms and use another DB.

Comment: Can you share your project so we can try to run it locally?